# Восстановление значения Search box'а в DataTables при установленном stateSave

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
var dataTable = $(dealsTableSelector).dataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    ...,
    drawCallback: function () {
        var api = this.api();
        var body = $(api.table().body());
        body.unhighlight();
        body.highlight(api.search());
    }
});
```

Есть таблица с подсветкой введенных в **search box** значений. Если перезагрузить страницу то таблица восстанавливает фильтра, страницы и т. д.

Но **search box** становится пустым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал в методе *drawCallback* искать и вставлять значение в **search box**, но тогда сам **search box** пропадает.

```
drawCallback: function() {
    ...
    var state = api.state.loaded();
    if(state){
        api.search(state.search.search);          // v 1
        $('#searchbox').val(state.search.search); // v 2
    }
    ...
}
```

В общем как можно восстановить значение фильтра в **search box**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` это и есть фильтр. Вы упомянули, что у Вас восстанавливаются фильтры...

Уж не custom ли фильтр ваш `search`?

Вот так выглядит восстановление содержимого custom фильтра:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = $('#dataTables').dataTable({
    "sDom": '<"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: 300,
    "stateLoadParams": function(settings, data) {
      $("#searchbox").val(data.search.search);
    }
  });

  $('#searchbox').on("input", function() {
    oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
  });

  $('#searchbtn').click(function() {
    oTable.fnFilter($(searchbox).val());
  });
});
```

Вот работающий [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/0t6sd8hg/)